# Random sampling in python from a list of values with new list having elements in power of 2. i.e, 32, 64, 128 etc

Tags: python, random

I have a list with 601 sorted values which are equidistant from each other starting from -15 to 15.
i.e A = [-15, -14.95, -14.90, …, 14.95, 15]. However, I want to create a new list with elements starting from the first value(-15). The no of elements in the new list should be in the power of 2. i.e 32 or 64 or 128 or 256 etc.

New_list = [2^n] elements. where n = 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 etc

Also these values in the new list should be from my list but equidistant(difference between 2 consecutive might differ from 0.05, which is the distance in the original list). Is there any way to do it using some library function preferably in Python. Any help appreciated.

Comment: "Also these values should be equidistant" - so it's _not_ actually a random sample?

Comment: What do you mean by: "no of values should be in a power of 2 in numbers. i.e 64, 128, 256" ?

Comment: @DaniMesejo - I mean that I want a list which has no of elements in the list as 64 or 128 or 256 etc.

Comment: @I'mahdi - No, I want a new list with no of elements as 32 or 64 or 128 or 256 etc

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - I have a list A = [-15, -14.95, -14.90, …, 14.95, 15] with 601 values. I want to pick elements from this list which are equidistant. The no of elements that I pick should be a power of 2.

Comment: @Dhruv What exactly do you mean by "equidistant"? How is the distance between values determined? Presumably it must be small enough to allow all 2^n elements to be selected - but it could be smaller, right? After all your conditons are met, there doesn't seem to be much room left for randomness...

Comment: When you say "random sampling", I'm assuming you want a homogeneous probability of selecting an individual combination of spacing and `n`, right? Or do you want to have `n` as an input and choose the spacings that are possible (e.g. n = 2 you can choose almost any spacing, n = 9 forces the minimum spacing)

Comment: @ekhumoro - I mean that currently the difference between 2 consecutive values are 0.05. I want to pick (32 or 64 or 128 elements) from my list staring from -15 where the difference between the next element and -15 may be some 0.05 or 0.10 or 0.15 etc. I can also increase the size of my list if 601 values are too less to pick such numbers.

Comment: @Dhruv So what exactly is "random" about this selection? From your description, it seems entirely deterministic, unless you shuffle the final result. That is, you just pick some starting value, then increment it by the difference until you have 2^n elements.

Comment: @ekhumoro Apologies if the word 'random' doesn't fit for my ask. But yes I want a new list starting from -15 and increment it by a difference until I have 2^n elements :)

Comment: @Dhruv So just `[start + diff * i for i in range(2^n)]`?

Comment: If you don't want random choice, please update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```py
import numpy as np


def get_sample(arr, power):
    num_elements = 2 ** power
    spacing = len(arr) // num_elements
    stop = spacing * num_elements

    sample = arr[:stop:spacing]
    return sample


A = np.linspace(-15, 15, 601)
print(get_sample(A, 0))
print(get_sample(A, 1))
print(get_sample(A, 2))
print(get_sample(A, 3))
print(get_sample(A, 4))
print(get_sample(A, 5))
```

Has the following results:

```
[-15.]
[-15.   0.]
[-15.  -7.5    0.     7.5]
[-15. -11.25  -7.5   -3.75   0.     3.75   7.5  11.25]
[-15. -13.15 -11.3   -9.45  -7.6   -5.75  -3.9  -2.05 -0.2  1.65 ...
[-15. -14.1  -13.2  -12.3  -11.4  -10.5   -9.6  -8.7  -7.8 -6.9  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for something like this. Solves the purpose.